# Why item overlap bottom border in jquery-ui sortable?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am little bit confused with little visual bug which I notice with next my code.

As you can see I have list. When user drag second item and drop it to top, first item goes down to second place. I notice that first item overlap bottom border. Why does this happen? It seems like something wrong maybe with placeholder.

Link: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/0kf4qdLn/23/)

```js
$(function () {
 $("#list").sortable({});
});
```

```css
.panel{
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: unset !important;
}
.panel .panel-heading{
  border-radius: unset;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.panel .panel-body {
    padding: unset;
}
.custom-list-group-item:hover {
    background-color: #DCEDC8;
    color: #424242;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-body .list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: unset;
    border-top-right-radius: unset;
}
.panel .panel-body .list-group .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: unset;
    border-bottom-right-radius: unset;
}
.panel .panel-body .list-group .list-group-item .pull-right {
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.panel .panel-body .list-group {
    margin-bottom: unset;
}
.panel .panel-body .list-group .list-group-item {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-success">
   <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">Title</h4>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
     <a class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
      <span>Create</span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="list" class="list-group ui-sortable">
        
          <div class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
            <span>Great Britain</span>
            <span class="pull-right">
           <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
           </button>
           <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
           </button>
           <a class="btn btn-info btn-white" href="">
            <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
           </a>
          </span>
          </div>
  
          <div class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
          <span>South Korea</span>
          <span class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
           </button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </button>
              <a class="btn btn-info btn-white">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your issue. The output of your code is true. What do you mean from "I notice that first item overlap bottom border. Why does this happen?".

Comment: Hello, bro! Try to move second item to top. In that case first item goes down and bottom border of panel (green line) became invisible.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how fix it, @AliSoltani ?

Comment: I think it's comes from `style` of dragged `div`. I need to check it carefully to give a solution.

Comment: Let me know if you can find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It's comes from your `CSS`. If you change CSS like below, it works properly.

Instead below

```
.panel .panel-body .list-group .list-group-item {
    border: none;
}
```

You need to use like below:

```
.panel .panel-body .list-group {
    border: none;
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/psnbbay8/10/)

Comment: Well, I tried this solution before. In my case I don't need border to items. Just try to zoom your solution and you will notice that item's bottom border 
overlaps panel's bottom border. In other worlds they are in the same level. Unfortunately I can't use this solution, anyway thanks!

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Well. Another solution is that add `height: 145px;` to `.panel` like https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/8nr0u9dj/2/.